# loop through current directory store directory and subdirectory name in a array without duplicates

Tags: shell-script, shell, filenames

I have a scenario where I am looping through all directories and subdirectories in a given path; if a file with specific extension (.txt) is found, store the name of the directories and subdirectories in an array. Later, I read and execute commands on those directories.

Here is what I am performing:

```
!/bin/bash
x=( $(find . -name "*.txt") ); echo "${x[@]}"
for item in "${x[@]}"; { echo "$item"; }
```

My current output is:

```
./dir1/file1.txt
./dir1/file2.txt
./dir2/subdir1/subdir2/file3.txt
```

but what I want to achieve is in the array `x` there should not be any duplicates even if the dir contains more than one `.txt` file. Additionally, I don't want to store the file name in as a path; the array should contain only the directory name.

The expected output:

```
./dir1
./dir2/subdir1/subdir2/
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `bash`:

```bsh
shopt -s globstar
shopt -s dotglob nullglob

dirs=( ./**/*.txt )          # glob the names
dirs=( "${dirs[@]%/*}" )     # remove the filenames at the end
```

This gives you an array of directory paths with possible duplicates.  To delete the duplicates, use an associative array:

```bsh
declare -A seen
for dirpath in "${dirs[@]}"; do
    seen["$dirpath"]=''
done

dirs=( "${!seen[@]}" )    # extract the keys from the "seen" hash
```

Then, to print them,

```bsh
printf '%s\n' "${dirs[@]}"
```

---

In the `zsh` shell, you would do it similarly, but use a unique array and the shell's fancy globbing qualifiers to strip off the filename at the end of the paths:

```bsh
typeset -U dirs

dirs=( ./**/*.txt(DN:h) )
```

The `D` and the `N` in the globbing qualifier after the pattern acts as `dotglob` and `nullglob` in `bash`, i.e., they enable matching of hidden names and remove the pattern if there are no matches at all.  The final `:h` gives you the "head" of the generated pathnames, i.e., the directory path without the filename at the end.

The `zsh` shell does not have to enable the use of `**` explicitly, as you have to do in `bash` with setting the `globstar` shell option.

Then, to print them,

```bsh
print -r -C1 -- $dirs
```

---

Also related:

- [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697)

Answer (score 0):

As a variant:

```
#!/bin/bash
x=$(for f in $(find . -name "*.txt"); do echo "${f%/*}"; done | sort -u )
for item in "${x[@]}"; { echo "$item"; }
```

Comment: thanks and if I want to exclude a specific directory ?

Comment: Since the question is tagged "Linux" they should be able to use GNU find's `-printf '%h\n'` (or better, `-printf '%h\0'` with `sort -zu`) to get the leading path components, which avoids the shell loop - see [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice)

Comment: Try after `mkdir -p 'foo /*/*/*/* *.txt'` for instance.